# How to combine 2 tables with same date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables with following data:

**TABLE 1 (dummy_daily)**

```
Entry               storenum                busidate              daily_budget
1                       1                   2017-07-01               4000
2                       1                   2017-07-02               3500
3                       1                   2017-07-03               2000
4                       1                   2017-07-04               6000
5                       1                   2017-07-05               1500
```

**TABLE 2 (site_labour)**

```
Lab_id              storenum                busidate              lab_hour
1123                    1                   2017-07-01               128
1124                    1                   2017-07-02               103
1125                    1                   2017-07-03               114
1126                    1                   2017-07-04               108
1127                    1                   2017-07-05               118
```

This is my current query to combine the 2 tables that have the same date to give result of `daily_budget` and `lab_hour`
QUERY:

```
SELECT
a.daily_budget as Ideal, c.lab_hour as Actual,
b.store_name, b.storenum,a.busidate
FROM dummy_daily a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum=a.storenum JOIN 
site_labour c ON b.storenum=c.storenum
WHERE b.storenum='1' AND 
(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' THEN c.lab_hour ELSE 0 END) 
AND (CASE WHEN a.busidate 
BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' THEN a.daily_budget ELSE 0 END)
```

But my current query give me a wrong result :

**Wrong Result of Current Query**

```
Ideal          Actual              storenum                 busidate
4000            128                   1                     2017-07-01
3500            128                   1                     2017-07-02
2000            128                   1                     2017-07-03
6000            128                   1                     2017-07-04
1500            103                   1                     2017-07-05
4000            103                   1                     2017-07-01
3500            103                   1                     2017-07-02
2000            103                   1                     2017-07-03
6000            103                   1                     2017-07-04
1500            103                   1                     2017-07-05
```

This data will continue until end of Actual 118

**Expected Result**

```
Ideal          Actual              storenum                 busidate
4000            128                   1                     2017-07-01
3500            103                   1                     2017-07-02
2000            114                   1                     2017-07-03
6000            108                   1                     2017-07-04
1500            118                   1                     2017-07-05
```

Comment: Can you also explain the logic behind joining the two tables?

Comment: I need to combine between this 2 tables to get 'daily_budget' and 'lab_hour' within  1 Query.

Comment: @NHH, let add more sample data so that we can understand what you want

Comment: I think you are missing `a.busidate=c.busidate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed one more table so its make confusion to create logic,
As per my understanding, I have created a SELECT statement. Please try this:-

```
    SELECT 
    dummy_daily.daily_budget as Ideal, site_labour.lab_hour as Actual,
    site_store.store_name, site_store.storenum, dummy_daily.busidate
    FROM dummy_daily 
    JOIN site_store 
    ON dummy_daily.storenum = site_store.storenum
    JOIN site_labour
    ON dummy_daily.storenum = site_labour.storenum
    WHERE (dummy_daily.storenum = 1)
    AND (dummy_daily.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05')
    AND (site_labour.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05')
    AND (dummy_daily.busidate = site_labour.busidate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the SQL below:

```
SELECT
a.daily_budget as Ideal, c.lab_hour as Actual,
b.store_name, b.storenum,a.busidate
FROM dummy_daily a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum=a.storenum AND b.busidate=a.busidate JOIN 
site_labour c ON b.storenum=c.storenum AND b.busidate=c.busidate
WHERE b.storenum='1' AND 
(CASE WHEN c.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' THEN c.lab_hour ELSE 0 END) 
AND (CASE WHEN a.busidate 
BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' THEN a.daily_budget ELSE 0 END)
```